# Can't connect to docker via ssh using testcontainer

Tags: docker, ssh, testcontainers

My task is connected to the container via ssh from tests.

I have dockefile:  (almost from https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/)

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN echo 'root:root' |chpasswd

RUN sed -i 's/^#?PermitRootLogin\s+.*/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i 's/UsePAM yes/#UsePAM yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh    
RUN apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile
EXPOSE 22

CMD    ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Then I use this dockerfile by testcontainer:

```
public static GenericContainer localServer(@NotNull Integer port, @NotNull String user, @NotNull String password, Path dockerfile) {
    return new GenericContainer(
      new ImageFromDockerfile()
        .withFileFromPath("Dockerfile", dockerfile))
      .withExposedPorts(port)
      .withFileSystemBind(FileUtil.getTempDirectory(), "/home/", BindMode.READ_WRITE);
```

When I run my test, the container successfully runs, but I can't connect via ssh. 49154 - is value from `sftp.getMappedPort(22)`

```
ssh root@localhost -p 49154
```

Got:
ssh: connect to host localhost port 32836: Connection refused

What's a detail I've missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.withExposedPorts(port)` - it seems that you're trying to externalize the port, while you image defines a static port "22".

Use `.withExposedPorts(22)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but “port” is actually constant = “22”.

Comment: then make sure that your image actually listens on all interfaces, not just "localhost". Have you tried to run it with just `docker run -p 22 my-image`?

Comment: Yes, I also can run docker with the terminal only:  ```dockerfile docker build -t image_name .```
 ```docker run -d -P --name container_name  image_name```
 ```docker port test_sshd 22```
 ```ssh root@localhost -p 32768``` 
  and it works

Comment: just in case, my OS is macOS

Comment: In your `docker run` example, you didn't map the `/home/` folder, but I see this in the example code you provided. Could you please double check that it is not caused by it?